# How to set Image resource to ImageView using DataBinding

Tags: android, xml, android-databinding

How can we use data binding in android to put image resource in an `ImageView`?

```
  <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/is_synced"
            android:src="@{model.pending ? @mipmap/pending: @mipmap/synced}"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

I want an image if pending is true and another image if pending is false. But it's showing error.How can I achieve this functionality?

Comment: I answered here a good solution. https://stackoverflow.com/a/52983092/6891563

Answer (score 59, accepted):

set image like this,

```
  <ImageView
        android:layout_width="28dp"
        android:layout_height="28dp"
        android:src="@{model.isActive ? @drawable/white_activated_icon :@drawable/activated_icon}"
        tools:src="@mipmap/white_activated_icon" />
```

Comment: I used it in recyclerview adapter which each item has 5 ImageView then, it causes performance decrease significantly. Because for each onBindViewHolder call, databinding check if statments. Now i prefer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37675475/6751083)

Comment: This doesn't work for me

Answer (score 103):

I tried this, and it works for me (buildToolsVersion: 24.0.1):

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    app:imageResource="@{item.avatarResId}"/>
```

just use `app:imageResource` to replace `android:src`, `android:src="@{item.avatarResId}"` doesn't works else define a custom `@BindAdapter("android:src")` for it.

but use `app:imageResource` doesn't need define a `@BindAdapter` additionally, because the ImageView has a method called `setImageResource()`, when you use `app:imageResource`, it will call `setImageResource()` automatically.

Comment: Thank you, it works. I just replaced `android:src` with `app:imageResource`.

Comment: thanks @Spark.Bao you saved me :D it works

Comment: If you cannot find `app:imageResource` try `app:loadImageResource` instead.

Comment: Remeber to add`<data><import type="your.package.R"/></data>` in xml

Answer (score 73):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36941125/703225):

define:

```
@BindingAdapter({"android:src"})
public static void setImageViewResource(ImageView imageView, int resource) {
    imageView.setImageResource(resource);
}
```

use:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:scaleType="center"
    android:src="@{viewModel.imageRes, default=@drawable/guide_1}"/>
```

Answer (score 18):

If you would like to pass an argument into the method like an `@IdRes` you can use

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <import type="<package_name>.R" />
    </data>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        app:load_image="@{R.drawable.image}" />
</layout>
```

Code

```
@BindingAdapter("load_image")
public static void loadImage(ImageView view, @IdRes int imageId) {
    //Logic
}
```

Comment: I reluctantly ended up following this answer. I wish there was a way to use the `@+id/blah` syntax so that I didn't need to define a new `<item name="blah" type="id" />` resource element in a separate file... alasssssss

Answer (score 15):

You can do this without doing anything programmatically if your data model contains the resource ID of the image.

Example:

```
<layout>

<data>
<import type="android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat" />            
<variable
name="roomInfoItem"
type="com.example......model.RoomInfoModel" /> </data>

<RelativeLayout> 

 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_room_info_item"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 />

</RelativeLayout>

</layout>
```

Just add the following line to your imageView (I wasn't able to format the code when I was adding it there):

```
android:src="@{ContextCompat.getDrawable(context,roomInfoItem.resId)}"
```

where `resId` contains `R.drawable.your_image_name`

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. Even when using the Groupie data binding library by Lisa Wray as well.

Comment: simply working as what I expected.

Answer (score 5):

Accorrding to this great article: [Loading images with Data Binding and Picasso](https://medium.com/android-news/loading-images-with-data-binding-and-picasso-555dad683fdc#.7asrl271q)

there are two ways to do it:

1. Using `@BindingAdapter`
2. `ObservableField` & custom Picasso Target

In Android Developers reference [Data Binding Guide](http://developer.android.com/tools/data-binding/guide.html), you would find only the first one.

Please read both articles.

More informations:

- http://www.mutualmobile.com/posts/using-data-binding-api-in-recyclerview
- https://blog.stylingandroid.com/data-binding-part-3/

Hope it help.

Comment: @piotrek1543, I am trying to load imageView using picasso in an item inside recyclerView using databainding, apparently when I scroll the up and down the images load again even if they were loaded a minute again, https://github.com/pankajnimgade/Tutorial101/tree/master/app/src/main/java/data/binding/list/activities/three

Comment: good article but , if you are getting data from an external server to populate the imageUrl, by the time the data arrives loadImage(ImageView view, String imageUrl) is already called --- seems there is no 2 way binding here?

Answer (score 1):

More details Refer here [Details](https://medium.com/android-news/loading-images-with-data-binding-and-picasso-555dad683fdc#.fjbexnm74) **Loading images with data binding and Picasso**

```
public class ProfileViewModel {
// The URL will usually come from a model (i.e Profile)
static final String IMAGE_URL = "http://cdn.meme.am/instances/60677654.jpg";
public ObservableField<Drawable> profileImage;
private BindableFieldTarget bindableFieldTarget;

public ProfileViewModel(Context context) {
    profileImage = new ObservableField<>();
    // Picasso keeps a weak reference to the target so it needs to be stored in a field
    bindableFieldTarget = new BindableFieldTarget(profileImage, context.getResources());
    Picasso.with(context)
            .load(IMAGE_URL)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
            .into(bindableFieldTarget);
}

public class BindableFieldTarget implements Target {

    private ObservableField<Drawable> observableField;
    private Resources resources;

    public BindableFieldTarget(ObservableField<Drawable> observableField, Resources resources) {
        this.observableField = observableField;
        this.resources = resources;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
        observableField.set(new BitmapDrawable(resources, bitmap));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
        observableField.set(errorDrawable);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
        observableField.set(placeHolderDrawable);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with all the attributes which do on have setters with same name. e.g. android:x wont work if setX() method is not there in that view likewise if we had setSrc() method on ImageView your code would have worked without custom binding adapter

Answer (score -1):

```
<ImageView ...
        app:svg="@{@drawable/ic_car_placeholder}" />
```

then

```
@BindingAdapter({"app:svg"})
public static void setImageViewResource(ImageView imageView, Drawable resource) {
    imageView.setBackgroundDrawable(resource);
}
```