# Set drawable resource ID in android:src for ImageView using data binding in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-databinding

I'm trying to set the drawable resource ID to *android:src* of ImageView using data binding.

Here is my object:

```
public class Recipe implements Parcelable {
    public final int imageResource; // Resource ID (e.g. R.drawable.some_image)
    public final String title;
    // ...

    public Recipe(int imageResource, String title /* ... */) {
        this.imageResource = imageResource;
        this.title = title;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Here is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="recipe"
            type="com.example.android.fivewaystocookeggs.Recipe" />
    </data>

    <!-- ... -->

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/recipe_image_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@{recipe.imageResource}" />

    <!-- ... -->

</layout>
```

And finally, the activity class:

```
// ...

public class RecipeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String RECIPE_PARCELABLE = "recipe_parcelable";
    private Recipe mRecipe;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mRecipe = getIntent().getParcelableExtra(RECIPE_PARCELABLE);
        ActivityRecipeBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_recipe);
        binding.setRecipe(mRecipe);
    }

    // ...

}
```

It doesn't display an image at all. What am I doing wrong?

BTW, it was perfectly working with the standard way:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_recipe);

    final ImageView recipeImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.recipe_image_view);
    recipeImageView.setImageResource(mRecipe.imageResource);

}
```

Answer (score 129, accepted):

**Answer as of Nov 10 2016**

[Splash's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35809290/set-drawable-resource-id-in-androidsrc-for-imageview-using-data-binding-in-andr#comment67950487_35809319) has highlighted that it is not necessary to use a custom property type (like `imageResource`). We can instead create multiple methods for `android:src` like so:

```java
public class DataBindingAdapters {

    @BindingAdapter("android:src")
    public static void setImageUri(ImageView view, String imageUri) {
        if (imageUri == null) {
            view.setImageURI(null);
        } else {
            view.setImageURI(Uri.parse(imageUri));
        }
    }

    @BindingAdapter("android:src")
    public static void setImageUri(ImageView view, Uri imageUri) {
        view.setImageURI(imageUri);
    }

    @BindingAdapter("android:src")
    public static void setImageDrawable(ImageView view, Drawable drawable) {
        view.setImageDrawable(drawable);
    }

    @BindingAdapter("android:src")
    public static void setImageResource(ImageView imageView, int resource){
        imageView.setImageResource(resource);
    }
}
```

---

**Old Answer**

You could always try to use an adapter:

```java
public class DataBindingAdapters {

    @BindingAdapter("imageResource")
    public static void setImageResource(ImageView imageView, int resource){
        imageView.setImageResource(resource);
    }
}
```

You can then use the adapter in your XML content like so:

```xml
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/recipe_image_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    imageResource="@{recipe.imageResource}" />
```

Be sure to notice that the name within the XML content matches the BindingAdapter annotation (imageResource).

The DataBindingAdapters class doesn't need to be declared anywhere in particular. The DataBinding mechanics will find it no matter (I believe).

Comment: It works by using `@BindingAdapter`. But, value should be `android:src`, not `imageResource`: `@BindingAdapter("android:src")`.

Thank you!

Comment: @YuriySeredyuk Nooooo! haha please. Doing that will override every single use of "android:src" within the xml across your **entire application** which you definitely **DON'T** want to be doing.

To get imageResource to work you have to change the xml for the imageView like i have done above, the databinding will work out what to put there

Comment: OK, I understood idea. Now using `<ImageView imageResource="@{recipe.imageResource}" />` and `@BindingAdapter("imageResource")`. I just missed `imageResource="@{recipe.imageResource}"` part from your code snipped :)

Comment: So then this line here `@BindingAdapter("imageResource")` defines a new key **imageResource** you can use in the xml to reference the resource ID.  It took me a bit to make that connection.. I think I got it though, Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't this need to be `app:imageResource`?

Comment: @NameSpace including app will make no difference, the only difference i have seen my self is that the ide's will no longer flag it as invalid

Comment: "Doing that will override every single use of "android:src" within the xml across your entire application"  Isn't databinding smart enough to only apply that attribute to ImageView, because that's whats defined in the function?  I think "android:src" would be preferable....consider what Android itself doe for ImageView binding adapters: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/data-binding/+/android-7.0.0_r7/extensions/baseAdapters/src/main/java/android/databinding/adapters/ImageViewBindingAdapter.java?autodive=0%2F

Comment: Oh yes sorry i did intend that to mean each use of "android:src" within imageview's across the application, but you do make a good poiint, i didn't realise the databinding was smart enough to match up the type given like in that example you have reference. Will modfiy my answer

Comment: I have similar problem. Depending on some cases I need to show one of 100 pngs, how to do that with data binding?

Comment: @hogar i personally wouldn't have my logic for doing that within the adapter, id work out the 1/100 image separately and then pass it on

Comment: @Joe Maher I do not get your point. Can you please clarify this a little bit? Thanks

Comment: what is imageView passed as a parameter in setImageDrawable method

Comment: Using a `@BindingAdapter("android:src")` that takes an `int` as the parameter clashes with `android:src="@{aBoolean ? @color/red : @color/green}"`. The color gets also passed to this adapter as an int and therfore the resource for `imageView.setImageResource(...)` cannot be resolved.

Comment: No need for a BindingAdapter. The method `ImageView.setImageResource` has a setter style name. Databinding binds setters automatically.

Comment: can be converted to Kotlin as extensions (a bit of code)

Answer (score 101):

There is no need for a custom `BindingAdapter` at all.
Just use

```
app:imageResource="@{yourResId}"
```

and it will work fine.

Check [this](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/binding-adapters.html#automatic-setting) for how it works.

Comment: I'm taking a look at the `ImageView` class and following the `setImageResource` method, seems that eventually is solved on `resolveUri` and there is if not zero validation. So that would work for `Int` I wonder what could happen if `Int?`. When bindings are executed, by example if something else call `executePendingBindings` then not nullable are defaulted to zero, nullables to null.

Comment: Remeber to add`<data><import type="your.package.R"/></data>` in xml

Answer (score 25):

Define:

```java
@BindingAdapter({"android:src"})
public static void setImageViewResource(ImageView imageView, int resource) {
    imageView.setImageResource(resource);
}
```

Use:

```xml
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:scaleType="center"
    android:src="@{viewModel.imageRes, default=@drawable/guide_1}"/>
```

Comment: where do I add that method

Comment: support add it in any class , maybe you can create a ImageDataBindingAdapter.class.

Answer (score 18):

Building upon [the answer from Maher Abuthraa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35809290/set-drawable-resource-id-in-androidsrc-for-imageview-using-data-binding-in-andr/47312208#47312208), this is what I ended up using in the XML:

```
android:src="@{context.getDrawable(recipe.imageResource)}"
```

The `context` variable [is available](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/expressions#variables) in the binding expression without any imports. Also, no custom `BindingAdapter` necessary. Only caveat: the method `getDrawable` has only been available since API 21.

Comment: By using `<import type="androidx.core.content.ContextCompat"/>` and the `android:src="@{ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, recipe.imageResource)}"` you can reach even lower API level.

Answer (score 13):

Never override standard SDK attributes when you create your own `@BindingAdapter`!

This is not a good approach for many reasons like:
it's going to prevent obtaining benefits of new fixes on an Android SDK update on that attribute. Also it might confuse developers and surely tricky for reusability (because it's unexpected to be overridden).

You may use a different namespace, like:

```
custom:src="@{recipe.imageResource}"
```

or

```
mybind:src="@{recipe.imageResource}"
```

------ start Update 2018-07-02

A namespace is not recommended to be used, so it is better to rely on a prefix or different name, such as:

```
app:custom_src="@{recipe.imageResource}"
```

or

```
app:customSrc="@{recipe.imageResource}"
```

------ end Update 2018-07-02

However, I would recommend a different solution as:

```
android:src="@{ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, recipe.imageResource)}"
```

The context view is ***always available*** inside the binding expression  `@{ ... }`

Comment: I think that code inside xml should be avoided as much as possible - it is not testable, it can pile up and it is not obvious. But i agree that overloading standard attributes can be confusing. I think the best way is to name new attribute differently, in this case "srcResId", but still use a BindingAdapter

Comment: "Edit" or "Update" [do not belong in answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131009/what-should-i-keep-out-of-my-posts-and-titles/131011#131011). The answer ought to be as if it was written today (there is a full revision history; nothing is lost by removing content from the current version).

Answer (score 13):

#### The more you can do with `DataBindingAdapter`

- You can set the **Image URL**, **File**, **Bitmap**, **Byte Array**, **Drawable**, **Drawable Id**, and almost anything by data binding.
- You can set error image and placeholder images too with [passing multiple parameters to a binding adapter](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/binding-adapters).

#### Set any of these types:

```
android:src="@{model.profileImage}"

android:src="@{roundIcon ? @drawable/ic_launcher_round : @drawable/ic_launcher_round}"

android:src="@{bitmap}"

android:src="@{model.drawableId}"

android:src="@{@drawable/ic_launcher}"

android:src="@{file}"

android:src="@{`https://placekitten.com/200/200`}"
```

**And for the mipmap resources**

```
android:src="@{@mipmap/ic_launcher}" <!--This will show Token recognition error at '@mipmap -->


android:src="@{R.mipmap.ic_launcher}" <!-- correct with improt R class -->
```

**Set an error image or placeholder image**

```
placeholderImage="@{@drawable/img_placeholder}"
errorImage="@{@drawable/img_error}"


<ImageView
    placeholderImage="@{@drawable/ic_launcher}"
    errorImage="@{@drawable/ic_launcher}"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:src="@{`https://placekitten.com/2000/2000`}"
    />
```

#### Tested all the types

[image: SC]

So that becomes possible with a single binding adapter. Just copy this method project.

```
public class BindingAdapters {
    @BindingAdapter(value = {"android:src", "placeholderImage", "errorImage"}, requireAll = false)
    public static void loadImageWithGlide(ImageView imageView, Object obj, Object placeholder, Object errorImage) {
        RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions();
        if (placeholder instanceof Drawable)
            options.placeholder((Drawable) placeholder);
        if (placeholder instanceof Integer)
            options.placeholder((Integer) placeholder);

        if (errorImage instanceof Drawable)
            options.error((Drawable) errorImage);
        if (errorImage instanceof Integer)
            options.error((Integer) errorImage);

        RequestManager manager = Glide.with(App.getInstance()).
                applyDefaultRequestOptions(options);
        RequestBuilder<Drawable> builder;

        if (obj instanceof String) {
            builder = manager.load((String) obj);
        } else if (obj instanceof Uri)
            builder = manager.load((Uri) obj);
        else if (obj instanceof Drawable)
            builder = manager.load((Drawable) obj);
        else if (obj instanceof Bitmap)
            builder = manager.load((Bitmap) obj);
        else if (obj instanceof Integer)
            builder = manager.load((Integer) obj);
        else if (obj instanceof File)
            builder = manager.load((File) obj);
        else if (obj instanceof Byte[])
            builder = manager.load((Byte[]) obj);
        else builder = manager.load(obj);
        builder.into(imageView);
    }
}
```

#### The reason I used Glide to load all objects

If you may ask me why I used [Glide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glide_API) to load drawable/ resource id, if instead I could use `imageView.setImageBitmap();` or `imageView.setImageResource();`? So the reason is that

- Glide is an efficient image loading framework that wraps media decoding, memory and disk caching. So you need not to worry about large size images and cache.
- To make for consistency for loading images. Now all types of image resources are loaded by Glide.

If you use [Picasso](https://square.github.io/picasso/), [Fresco](https://github.com/facebook/fresco), or any other image loading library, you can make changes in the `loadImageWithGlide` method.

Comment: `    errorImage="@{@drawable/ic_launcher}"`. This thing doesn't even compile for me

Comment: @VivekMishra Perhaps your ic_launcher is in mipmap?, try @mipmap/ic_launcher.

Comment: @VivekMishra Can you paste your relevant error log? Did you add this method in your binding util class?

Comment: ****/ data binding error ****msg:Cannot find the getter for attribute 'app:src' with value type java.lang.String on com.zuowei.circleimageview.CircleImageView.
I tried with both android as well as app namespace and both of them didn't worked for me. I have also replaced default imageview with circleImageView in the parameter

Comment: Also I have created binding Adapter in a separate class

Comment: @VivekMishra does this occur after only adding `errorImage` attr? Also CIV is inherted from ImageView so you need not change Binding Adapter parameters.

Comment: I am using placeHolderImage and src attribute from the binding adapter

Comment: @VivekMishra It is `placeholderImage` in above method, have you done a type mistake?

Comment: @BindingAdapter(value = *arrayOf("android:src", "placeholderImage", "errorImage"), requireAll = false)

Answer (score 7):

For **Kotlin** put this to a top level utils file. No static / companion context is needed:

```
@BindingAdapter("android:src")
fun setImageViewResource(view: ImageView, resId : Int) {
    view.setImageResource(resId)
}
```

Answer (score 7):

There isn't any need for a custom BindingAdapter at all. [Just use](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58747016/15129232):

*data*:

```xml
<data>
    <import type="com.example.R"/>
      :
</data>
```

ImageView:

```xml
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:imageResource="@{gender == 0 ? R.drawable.male : R.drawable.female}" />
```

Comment: You helped me with this  normally I would avoid passing resource ids, but in my case it was needed because of a custom UI-lib provided by third party. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This works for me. I would have added it to hqzxzwb's answer as a comment, but due to reputation limitations.

I have this in my view model:

```
var passport = R.drawable.passport
```

Then in my XML content, I have

```
android:src="@{context.getDrawable(model.passort)}"
```

And that’s it.

Comment: OK but you forget mention that you must import context. Could you update your answer?

Comment: Related: *[Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/)*.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```java
public Drawable getImageRes() {
    return mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon);
}
```

```xml
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="center"
    android:src="@{viewModel.imageRes}"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here a complete breakdown of the approach with data binding using `BindingAdapter`:

I will also use the `BindingAdapter` in this example. Preparing the XML content:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="model"
            type="blahblah.SomeViewModel"/>
    </data>

    <!-- Blah blah -->

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView"
        app:appIconDrawable="@{model.packageName}"/>

    <!-- Blah blah -->
</layout>
```

So here I am keeping only the important stuff:

- `SomeViewModel` is my `ViewModel` I use for data binding. You can also use a class that extends `BaseObservable` and use `@Bindable`. However, the `BindingAdapter` in this example, **doesn't have to** be in a `ViewModel` or `BaseObservable` class! A plain class will do! This will be illustrated later.
- `app:appIconDrawable="@{model.packageName}"`. Yes... this was really causing me headaches! Let's break it down:

  - `app:appIconDrawable`: This can be anything: `app:iCanBeAnything`! Really. You can also keep `"android:src"`! However, take a note on your choice, we will use it later!
  - "@{model.packageName}": If you worked with [data binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/), this is familiar. I'll show how this is used later.

Let's assume we use this simple Observable class:

```
public class SomeViewModel extends BaseObservable {
   private String packageName; // This is what @{model.packageName}
                               // accesses via the getPackageName()!!!
                               // Of course this needs to be set at some
                               // point in your program, before it makes
                               // sense to use it in the BindingAdapter.

   @Bindable
   public String getPackageName() {
       return packageName;
   }

   public void setPackageName(String packageName) {
       this.packageName = packageName;
       notifyPropertyChanged(BR.packageName);
   }

   // The "appIconDrawable" is what we defined above!
   // Remember, they have to align!! As we said, we can
   // choose whatever "app:WHATEVER". The BindingAdapter
   // and the XML content need to be aligned. That's it! :)
   //
   // The name of the function, i.e., setImageViewDrawable, can also be
   // whatever we want! It doesn't matter.
   @BindingAdapter({"appIconDrawable"})
   public static void setImageViewDrawable(ImageView imageView, String packageName) {
       imageView.setImageDrawable(Tools.getAppIconDrawable(imageView.getContext(), packageName));
   }
}
```

As promised, you can also move the `public static void setImageViewDrawable()`, to some other class, e.g., maybe you can have a class that has a collection of `BindingAdapters`:

```
public class BindingAdapterCollection {
   @BindingAdapter({"appIconDrawable"})
   public static void setImageViewDrawable(ImageView imageView, String packageName) {
       imageView.setImageDrawable(Tools.getAppIconDrawable(imageView.getContext(), packageName));
   }
}
```

Another important remark is that in my `Observable` class I used `String packageName` to pass extra info to the `setImageViewDrawable`. You can also choose for example `int resourceId`, with the corresponding getters/setters, for which the adapter becomes:

```
public class SomeViewModel extends BaseObservable {
   private String packageName; // This is what @{model.packageName}
                               // accesses via the getPackageName()!!!
   private int resourceId;     // If you use this, don't forget to update
                               // your XML content with: @{model.resourceId}

   @Bindable
   public String getPackageName() {
       return packageName;
   }

   public void setPackageName(String packageName) {
       this.packageName = packageName;
       notifyPropertyChanged(BR.packageName);
   }

   @Bindable
   public int getResourceId() {
       return packageName;
   }

   public void setResourceId(int resourceId) {
       this.resourceId = resourceId;
       notifyPropertyChanged(BR.resourceId);
   }

   // For this you use: app:appIconDrawable="@{model.packageName}" (passes String)
   @BindingAdapter({"appIconDrawable"})
   public static void setImageViewDrawable(ImageView imageView, String packageName) {
       imageView.setImageDrawable(Tools.getAppIconDrawable(imageView.getContext(), packageName));
   }

   // For this you use: app:appIconResourceId="@{model.resourceId}" (passes int)
   @BindingAdapter({"appIconResourceId"})
   public static void setImageViewResourceId(ImageView imageView, int resource) {
       imageView.setImageResource(resource);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following:

```
android:src="@{expand?@drawable/ic_collapse:@drawable/ic_expand}"
```

Comment: We can, but what is it supposed to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

The key point of the solution is we need to give the type as `type="android.graphics.drawable.Drawable"`

**The explanation is in the below**

Let's say we have two layouts, *first_layout.xml* and *second_layout.xml*. And we will send drawable from the first to the second.

In file *first_layout.xml*:

```xml
<include
    android:id="@+id/home_last_trip"
    layout="@layout/second_layout.xml"
    app:myCustomImage="@{someCondition == 1 ? @drawable/your_image_1 :@drawable/your_image_1 }"/>
```

In file *second_layout.xml*:

```xml
<data>
    <variable
        name="myCustomImage"
        type="android.graphics.drawable.Drawable" />
</data>
```

You can use this data like this:

```xml
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/left_icon"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/_25"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_25"
    android:src="@{myCustomImage}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [Fresco](https://github.com/facebook/fresco) (Facebook image library):

```
 public class YourCustomBindingAdapters {

    //app:imageUrl="@{data.imgUri}"
    @BindingAdapter("bind:imageUrl")
    public static void loadImage(SimpleDraweeView imageView, String url) {
        if (url == null) {
            imageView.setImageURI(Uri.EMPTY);
        } else {
            if (url.length() == 0)
                imageView.setImageURI(Uri.EMPTY);
            else
                imageView.setImageURI(Uri.parse(url));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your view state or view model class;

```kotlin
fun getSource(context: Context): Drawable? {
    return ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.your_source)
}
```

In your XML content;

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton
   .
   .
   .
   android:src="@{viewState.getSource(context)}"
```

Comment: What programming language? [Kotlin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kotlin_(programming_language))?

Answer (score -1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <data>
        <variable
           name="model"
           type="YourViewModel"/>
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
          android:paddingStart="@dimen/dp16"
          android:paddingTop="@dimen/dp8"
          android:paddingEnd="@dimen/dp8"
          android:paddingBottom="@dimen/dp8">

          <ImageView
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
              android:src="@{model.selected ? @drawable/check_fill : @drawable/check_empty}"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Answer (score -1):

Set the image like this,

```xml
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="28dp"
    android:layout_height="28dp"
    android:src="@{model.isActive ? @drawable/white_activated_icon :@drawable/activated_icon}"
    tools:src="@mipmap/white_activated_icon" />
```

Answer (score -1):

One more example using `@IdRes` and `@BindingAdapter`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <import type="hello.R" />
    </data>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        app:show_image="@{R.drawable.image}" />
</layout>
```

```
@BindingAdapter("show_image")
public static void loadImage(ImageView view, @IdRes int imageId) {
}
```