# How to databinding image loading with Glide?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding

I am trying to load image with databinding. But I never got over it. Where's my problem? Below is my code and layout construction.

MyItemViewModel.kt

```
  @BindingAdapter("imageUrl")
    fun loadImage(view: RoundedImageView, url: String) = Glide.with(view.context).load(url).into(view)
```

layout.xml

```
<data>

    <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.myapp.app.ui.activity.albumlist.AlbumItemViewModel"/>
</data>

  <com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:id="@+id/ivRoundedAlbum"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/unit_20_dp"
                app:riv_corner_radius="8dp"
                app:imageUrl="@{viewModel.data.cover}"
                android:layout_height="60dp"/>
```

Comment: You'll need to make your **fun loadImage** static. Put `@JvmStatic` to it. If it provides error than move it to companion object.

Comment: @Hasan What is the exact error is url is "null"  or some compile time error is occuring.?

Comment: @JeelVankhede it gives error. I transferred into the model again gives error. ( Only members in named objects and companion objects can be  annotated with @JvmStatic)

Comment: your  function should be void remove = and but {} @HasanKucuk

Comment: @yash786 url comes full but I can't load imageview with databinding.

Comment: do you have the internet permission in your manifest?

Comment: @Blackbelt yes, added.

Comment: Can you pls check out the link which I have mentioned in my answer. It will definitely help you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set drawable resource ID in android:src for ImageView using data binding in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35809290/set-drawable-resource-id-in-androidsrc-for-imageview-using-data-binding-in-andr)

Comment: You can go ahead on the route of creating a BindingAdapter. That is by far the best way I think of loading images in recyclerview items with Glide. [Here's a simple tutorial](https://ayusch.com/databinding-with-glide-android/) if you're into articles. It's the cleanest way to implement this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to make **url** parameter nullable, and guard against null like this:

```
@BindingAdapter("imageUrl")
fun loadImage(view: RoundedImageView, url: String?) {
    if (!url.isNullOrEmpty()) {
        .....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

`BindingAdapter` methods should be *static*, so marking it `@JvmStatic` would help in this case.

But that will generate **'compile time error'** that *"methods can't be static inside class"* and so it should be moved to **companion object** or **named objects**.

In your case, you're having method in *class member level* so moving it to **companion object** will help. So for **`MyItemViewModel.kt`** make companion object and move method there like below :

```
class MyItemViewModel{
    //Some code
    companion object {

        @JvmStatic
        @BindingAdapter("imageUrl")
        fun loadImage(view: RoundedImageView, url: String) { // This methods should not have any return type, = declaration would make it return that object declaration.
            Glide.with(view.context).load(url).into(view)
        }
    }
    //Some other code
}
```

> Note: Also remove method declaration with `=`. Binding methods should have return type `Unit`.

---

**Edit:** One can also use method `Glide.with(view)` as @hmac suggested in comment, but ...

Things to consider before using this `Glide.with(view)`:

1. Your view should be attached before using it from Activity/Fragment. Best usecase for this method is Custom View/ViewGroup.
2. Consider layout hierarchy before using this method as too many nested/large hierarchy layouts are discouraged to use that method. It becomes inefficient for such layouts.
3. Also note that, if view is inside non-support fragment class or context is of non-support fragment than that can produce noisy log as [documentation](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/javadocs/400/com/bumptech/glide/Glide.html#with-android.view.View-) indicates, first migrate to support library *(Now considered as AndroidX)*  instead before using this method!

Comment: Where is the documentation in Glide that dictates BindingAdapter methods should be static?

Comment: I think using `Glide.with(view)` is preferable, if you check the code and documentation this will respect the lifecycle of the Fragment (or Activity) that the view is shown in. `with(context)` "will only have application level options applied and will not be started or stopped based on lifecycle events...is appropriate for resources that will be used outside of the normal fragment or activity lifecycle"

Answer (score 4):

This work fine for me

```
             <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    bind:image="@{subcategory.image}"
                    bind:placeholder="@{@drawable/no_imge}"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />




  @BindingAdapter("image","placeholder")
    fun setImage(image: ImageView, url: String?, placeHolder: Drawable) {

        if (!imageUrl.isNullOrEmpty()){

          Glide.with(image.context).load(url).centerCrop()
       .placeholder(R.drawable.no_imge)
                    .into(image)
        }
        else{
            image.setImageDrawable(placeHolder)
        }


    }
```

Comment: which namespace need to add for bind:

Comment: @SathishGadde, write app instead of bind

Answer (score 4):

It would be more convenient to create a [binding adapter](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/binding-adapters) which accepts multiple optional attributes so you can customize the loading request. Here's an example of such adapter.

```kotlin
@BindingAdapter(
  "srcUrl",
  "circleCrop",
  "placeholder",
  requireAll = false // make the attributes optional
)
fun ImageView.bindSrcUrl(
  url: String,
  circleCrop: Boolean = false,
  placeholder: Drawable?,
) = Glide.with(this).load(url).let { request ->

  if (circleCrop) {
    request.circleCrop()
  }

  if (placeholder != null) {
    request.placeholder(placeholder)
  }

  request.into(this)
}
```

And you can use it like this:

```xml
<ImageView
  ...
  app:srcUrl="@{someUrl}"
  app:placeholder="@{@drawable/ic_placeholder}"
  app:circleCrop="@{true}" />
```

You can also find an example in sources of the [Owl](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android-examples/tree/develop/Owl) - an official Android sample app on GitHub. See [BindingAdapters.kt](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android-examples/blob/develop/Owl/app/src/main/java/com/materialstudies/owl/util/BindingAdapters.kt).

Answer (score 2):

```
@JvmStatic
@BindingAdapter("glide")
fun glide(view: ShapeableImageView, url: String?) {
   if (!url.isNullOrEmpty()) {
      Glide.with(view).load(url).into(view)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best practise should be to create a separate variable for imageUrl of type string in layout.xml. BindingAdapter should be in model class. Also, the BindingAdapter method should be static as pointed out in comments. You can do it by wrapping inside a companion object with `@JvmStatic` annotation. For more details check [this](https://androidwave.com/loading-images-using-data-binding/)

```
    <variable
        name="imageUrl"
        type="String" />
```

Comment: To get imageurl at runtime we have to mentioned the path of the class where the url object is stored

Comment: What class should bindinAdapter be in exactly? Model.kt, AlbumItemViewModel.kt, AlbumViewModel.kt, AlbumAdapter.kt?

Comment: BindingAdapter should be in model class

Comment: : Required DataBindingComponent is null in class RowAlbumListBindingImpl. A BindingAdapter in com.myapp.app.model.AlbumList.Companion is not static and requires an object to use, retrieved from the DataBindingComponent. If you don't use an inflation method taking a DataBindingComponent, use DataBindingUtil.setDefaultComponent or make all BindingAdapter methods static.

Comment: Yes the bindingAdapter method should be static as already mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

use app:glideSrc like this

```
           <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/sender_profile_image_view"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/email_sender_profile_image_size"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/email_sender_profile_image_size"
                android:contentDescription="@string/email_sender_profile_content_desc"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:glideCircularCrop="@{true}"
                app:glideSrc="@{email.sender.avatar}"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/sender_text_view"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/recipient_text_view"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                tools:src="@drawable/avatar_3" />
```

and in BindingAdapter

```
@BindingAdapter(
  "glideSrc",
  "glideCenterCrop",
  "glideCircularCrop",
  requireAll = false
)
fun ImageView.bindGlideSrc(
  @DrawableRes drawableRes: Int?,
  centerCrop: Boolean = false,
  circularCrop: Boolean = false
) {
  if (drawableRes == null) return

  createGlideRequest(
    context,
    drawableRes,
    centerCrop,
    circularCrop
  ).into(this)
}

private fun createGlideRequest(
  context: Context,
  @DrawableRes src: Int,
  centerCrop: Boolean,
  circularCrop: Boolean
): RequestBuilder<Drawable> {
val req = Glide.with(context).load(src)
  if (centerCrop) req.centerCrop()
  if (circularCrop) req.circleCrop()
     return req
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Layout:

```
<data>
     <import type="com.example.package.R"/>
</data>

<ImageView
     android:id="@+id/logo"
     android:contentDescription="@string/logo"
     android:scaleType="fitCenter"
     app:gif = "@{R.drawable.logo}" />
```

Data Binding Utils:

```
@BindingAdapter("gif")
fun ImageView.setGif(res: Int) {
    Glide.with(this).load(res).into(this);
}
```