# Databinding android update imageview

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding

Hi I'm try to update imageview with databinding but i cent get how to do it right.

my var

```
@BindingAdapter({"bind:someImage"})
        public  void loadIt(ImageView view, String imageUrl) {
            Picasso.with(view.getContext())
                    .load(getSomeImage())
                    .placeholder(android.R.drawable.alert_dark_frame)
                    .into(view);
}

 public void setSomeImage(){
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.someImage);
    }
```

my layout

```
<ImageView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:id="@+id/imagePath"
      app:imageUrl="@{var.someImage}"/>
```

I have search but can't find solution....
links = [link1](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html) , [Link2](https://medium.com/android-news/loading-images-with-data-binding-and-picasso-555dad683fdc#.r4mato3kz) , [Link 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34607028/how-to-set-image-resource-to-imageview-using-databinding)

Answer (score 6):

you are using wrong property to call Binding method, as you have defined `@BindingAdapter({"bind:someImage"})` you need to use `someImage` while calling it from xml

```
<ImageView
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:id="@+id/imagePath"
  app:someImage="@{var.someImage}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your are not using the same value u have set in the binding adapter, you set `@BindingAdapter({"bind:someImage"})` and using `app:imageUrl`

use this instead:

```
<ImageView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:id="@+id/imagePath"
      bind:someImage="@{var.someImage}"/>
```

Example:

```
@BindingAdapter("loadImageUrl")
fun loadImageUrl(imageView: ImageView, url: String) {
    Glide.with(imgView).load(url)
        .placeholder(PLACE_HOLDER_IMAGE)
        .into(imageView)
}
```

```
                <ImageView
                    loadImageUrl="@{vm.url}"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without doing anything programmatically if your data model contains the resource ID of the image.

Example:

```
<layout>

<data>
<import type="android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat" />            
<variable
name="roomInfoItem"
type="com.example......model.RoomInfoModel" /> </data>

<RelativeLayout> 

 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_room_info_item"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 />

</RelativeLayout>

</layout>
```

Just add the following line to your imageView (I wasn't able to format the code when I was adding it there):

**android:src="@{ContextCompat.getDrawable(context,roomInfoItem.resId)}"**

where resId contains R.drawable.your_image_name